# How can I migrate moodle system from 1one server to another? Moodledata folder is about 1TB

Tags: linux, centos, moodle

Такая ситуация, что нужно перевести систему Мудл с одного сервера на другой. В тексте приложил ссылку на официальную документацию Moodle по миграции с сервера на сервер. С помощью команды rsync перевел .sql файл и папку содержащую папку кодов moodle. Теперь осталось перевести папку Moodledata, которая весит порядка 1 ТБ. Пытался архивировать, но не увидел эффективности, потому что архивный файл .tar.gz превышал 840 GB. Теперь вопрос, собираюсь напрямую через rsync перебросить moodledata на второй сервер, но какой нужно указать путь? Напрямую в хост-систему не поместится

Немного не понимаю принцип работы RAID-1, нужно чтобы rsync перебросил папку на один из дисков объемом 5.5 ГБ

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Comment: это русский stackoverflow, пожалуйста, переведите вопрос

Comment: При использования `rsync`, никакого `.tar.gz` на выходе не будет. Не надо ничего архивировать при использовании `rsync`